# dplyr::mutate changes row numbers, how to keep them?

Tags: r, row-number, dplyr

I am using lme4::lmList on a tibble to obtain the coefficients of linear fit lines fitted for each subject (id) in my data. What I actually want is a nice long chain of pipes because I don't want to keep any of this output, just use it for a slope/intercept plot.  However, I am running into a problem. lmList is creating a dataframe where the row numbers are the original subject ID numbers.  I want to keep that information, but as soon as I use mutate on the output, the row numbers change to be sequential from 1. I tried rescuing them first by using rowid_to_column but that just gives me a column of sequential numbers from 1 too. What can I do, other than drop out of the pipe and put them in a column with base R? Is unique(a_df$id) really the best solution? I had a look around on here but didn't see a question like this one.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(Matrix)
library(lme4)
a_df <- tibble(id = c(rep(4, 3), rep(11, 3), rep(12, 3), rep(42, 3)),
          age = c(rep(seq(1, 3), 4)),
          hair = 1 + (age*2) + rnorm(12) + as.vector(sapply(rnorm(4), function(x) rep(x, 3))))

# as.data.frame to get around stupid RStudio diagnostics bug
int_slope <- coef(lmList(hair ~ age | id, as.data.frame(a_df))) %>%
  setNames(., c("Intercept", "Slope"))
# Notice how the row numbers are the original subject ids?
print(int_slope)

    Intercept    Slope
4   2.9723596 1.387635
11  0.2824736 2.443538
12 -1.8912636 2.494236
42  0.8648395 1.680082

int_slope2 <- int_slope %>% mutate(ybar = Intercept + (mean(a_df$age) * Slope))
# Look!  Mutate has changed them to be the numbers 1 to 4
print(int_slope2)

   Intercept    Slope     ybar
1  2.9723596 1.387635 5.747630
2  0.2824736 2.443538 5.169550
3 -1.8912636 2.494236 3.097207
4  0.8648395 1.680082 4.225004

# Try to rescue them with rowid_to_column
int_slope3 <- int_slope %>% rowid_to_column(var = "id")
# Nope, 1 to 4 again
print(int_slope3)

  id  Intercept    Slope
1  1  2.9723596 1.387635
2  2  0.2824736 2.443538
3  3 -1.8912636 2.494236
4  4  0.8648395 1.680082
```

Thanks,

SJ

Comment: Those aren't row numbers, they are row *names* that happen to look like numbers. The author [does not think they are a good idea](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1830#issuecomment-219416777) in general, so makes no attempt to preserve them. If you need that metadata to remain with the data, I suggest you bring it into the frame, perhaps with `tibble::rownames_to_column` (or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dplyr/tidyverse` universe [doesn't "believe in" row names](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1830#issuecomment-219416777). Any data that is important for an observation should be included in a column. The `tibble` package includes a function to move row names into a column. Try

```
int_slope %>% rownames_to_column()
```

before any mutates.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like asking for help to make you see the answer.  Those aren't row numbers, they're numeric row names.  Of course they are!  Non-contiguous row numbers make no sense.  rownames_to_column is my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Why you just don´t create another 'ybar' column on int_slope?

```
int_slope$ybar<- Intercept + mean(a_df$age) * Slope
```

Comment: I was going to, but I wanted to do it with mutate.  Whereupon I lost the rownames, because I was being thick and not realising that was what they were.